# Copy to clipboard does not work in a terminal

Tags: 11.10, unity, command-line, shortcuts

Since upgrading to 11.10 and unity, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work anymore.  Paste works well, and also selecting the command from the menu.  The shortcut is properly defined in the preferences dialog.

Any cure?

Comment: does pressing the middle mouse key still paste the selected content?

Comment: yes. paste also works with ctrl+shift+v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:  The [Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper) app grabbed this shortcut key, but silently failed to open it's applet, providing no visual clue.

Solved!